# How to add updated date and time to the canvas area using fabric js?

Tags: vue.js, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to add the current date and time to the canvas area.
We can add the current date and time using the object.
But the date and time value are not updating continuously, Please suggest me a way how to add current date and time to the canvas when we click on the button.

Added complete code to add time to the canvas using fabric. The same code is written to add the date to canvas area.

```js
//This file has a method to addTimeText which is called on the button click and moment package to get the updated time value

import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import moment from "moment";

export default {
    methods: {
        addTimeText() {
            let isMouseDown = false;
            let object = null;
            this.getFabric().on('mouse:down', ({e}) => {
                isMouseDown = true;
                const pointer = this.getFabric().getPointer(e);
                object = new fabric.TruTime('', {
                    top: pointer.y,
                    left: pointer.x,
                    width: 250,
                });

                object.on('editing:exited', () => {

                    this.afterAdding(object);
                });

                this.getFabric().add(object);
                this.getFabric().setActiveObject(object).requestRenderAll();

                object.enterEditing();
            });

        },
    }
}

//new file has content related to the above JS file 

import Helper     from "./helper";
import FabricJS   from "fabric";
import { fabric } from "fabric";
import moment from "moment";
fabric.TruTime = FabricJS.fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox,
    {
        type      : "tru-text",

        initialize: function(text, options) {
            options = options || {};
            if (!options.uuid) {
                options = Helper.setDefaultProperties(
                    {
                        ...options, fill: "#000",
                        backgroundColor : "transparent",
                        fontFamily      : "Open Sans",
                        fontWeight      : 400,
                        fontFiles       : [
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto.css",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Black.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf",
                            //     "assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf"
                        ]
                    });
            }

            this.callSuper("initialize", text, options);
        },

        hasTag(value) {
            return [
                this.type,
                "font",
                "paragraph",
                "background",
                "position"].includes(value);
        },
        updateCurrentTime() {
            this.currentTime = moment().format('LTS');
            return this.currentTime;
        },
        toObject: function() {
            const svg = Helper.svg(this);
            const encodedSvg = btoa(svg);
            return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper("toObject"),
                {
                    uuid: this.uuid,
                    svg : encodedSvg,
                    text: this.updateCurrentTime()
                });
        }
    });

fabric.TruTime.async = true;
setInterval(() => object.text = this.updateCurrentTime(), 1000);
fabric.TruTime.fromObject = (object, callback) => {
    const truTime = new fabric.TruText(object.text, object);
    callback && callback(truTime);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to ensure vue is capturing your changes.